# how to replace all the occurrence of specified characters from a dictionary

Tags: python, encryption

i am currently working on a encryption decryption program . so i have a original string variable and then i convert the string into special character string using my dictionary . Now if some one gives me special character string again , how do i decrypt it ? i am trying this code but , it does not work .

``````````
enc_str= "`~```~`~`````" # this is 0315
dnory = {'0': '~', '1': '~`', '2': '~``', '3': '~```', '4': '~````', '5': '~`````', '6': '~``````', '7': '~```````', '8': '~````````', '9': '~`````````'}

def decrypt(dnory,enc_str):
    dec_list = []
    dnory_reverse = dict([[v,k] for k,v in dnory.items()])
    for key in dnory_reverse :
        if(enc_str.find(key)>0) :
            dec_list.append(dnory_reverse[key])
    print(dec_list)

decrypt(dnory,enc_str)
``````````

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: You'll want to reverse your dictionary here.

Comment: how would you represent 1315 and 3015?

Comment: How is possible to distinguish 3015 and 415 in your original logic?

Comment: I think you meant `0: '~'`?

Comment: I'm  seeing 0100110000, or in the horror version , 010012000!

Comment: does not work means that my string i.e enc_str= "`~```~`~`````"  does not get converted to 0315

Comment: 0 is ` and 1 is ~` they have different values

Comment: @AshishAcharya i see a problem there . But how do i solve that ?

Comment: Perhaps simply use `0: '~'` as suggested by @MadPhysicist

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: @pankaj. Different values is insufficient. The issue is that a given string can be interpreted as many possible sequences. The interpretation is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't understand this code.

For all keys in dnory_reverse (for all encrypted numbers) you check if enc_str contain this key and append associated decrypted number to dec_list.

Conclusion: You forgot about order.

I think you should change dnory to this:

```````````
dnory = {'0': '~`', '1': '~``', '2': '~```', '3': '~````', '4': '~`````', '5': '~``````', '6': '~```````', '7': '~````````', '8': '~`````````', '9': '~``````````'}
```````````

and use split('~') on enc_str to get list of encrypted numbers.

I think that I haven't to describe next steps, but remember that you have '~' in dnory what doesn't exist in list created using split()

Useful links:
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

PS
dict() doesn't sort keys alphabetically but randomly so your code return various output.

```
# this is comment in Python
// not this
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for your encoding to distinguish between 0 and 1. For example, how would you represent 3015?

For 1 to 9, however, the following code is sufficient:

```
print(''.join(str(len(i)) for i in enc_str.split('~')))
```

Output:

```
1315
```

If you change your keys to this:

``````````
dnory = {'0': '~', '1': '~`', '2': '~``', '3': '~```', '4': '~````', '5': '~`````', '6': '~``````', '7': '~```````', '8': '~````````', '9': '~`````````'}
``````````

...there is a way to get it to work like so:

``````
enc_str= "~```~`~`````"
print(''.join(str(len(i)) for i in enc_str.split('~')))
``````

Output:

```
0315
```

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus, yeah but how would you distinguish them?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to distinguish 3015 and 415.

Comment: @Marcus. It's impossible to distinguish any number from the previous number followed by zero, or the number two back followed by two zeros, etc.

Comment: @AshishAcharya so now what i observe is if i go with totally another encoding in future i must have  a separator to separate dictonary value in the string .